# How to display Media content in MS teams

Tags: youtube, botframework, microsoft-teams

If we put the following code directly in MS teams it's rendering the video. how to achieve this by sending from the bot.

```
<div>
    <iframe src="youtube.com/embed/kH5nWz4Uay0" height="150px" width="100%" allowfullscreen=""></iframe> 
</div>
```

Comment: <div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kH5nWz4Uay0" height="150px" width="100%" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57393567/edit) your question to include the code with the proper formatting. Comments are for clarifications, not for complementing the question! Welcome to SO by the way!

Answer (score 1):

@Shaik Bots in Microsoft Teams does not support video cards. You could use [TaskModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-bots) to open a video inside teams. Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp) to achieve the same.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Currently there is no other way. Are you facing any problem with TaskModule?

Comment: @Shaik if this answer solved your problem, consider [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Hi @Gousia-MSFT what version of adaptive card does MsTeams support? I noticed you need v1.1 to embed video (https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Media.html), but it seems only v1.0 is supported.

Comment: Microsoft Teams currently supports v1.0 of Adaptive Cards, with additional support for newer versions planned. To open a video inside Task Module you don't need and Adaptive card. You could pass the url of the video to the Task Module. Please refer to the sample I have attached in my answer. It has a video opened inside Task Module.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I am little confusing going through the sample code and implement my scenario. can you help me in step by step how to achieve pls. from the below sample code, where do we need to pass videio link/id card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction("invoke", TaskModuleUIConstants.YouTube.ButtonTitle, null,
                new BotFrameworkCardValue<string>()
                {
                    Data = TaskModuleUIConstants.YouTube.Id
                }));

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT - Here  Data = TaskModuleUIConstants.YouTube.Id, how YouTube.Id looks like can I have an example pls.

Comment: @Shaik- Those are just POCOs used to serialize and send the final JSON in response. Please try out the sample locally so that you can check what all values are being passed in response. Here is the documentation on [Invoking a task module via task/fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-bots#invoking-a-task-module-via-taskfetch).

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Okay! Thank you. Let me go through it.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT i am getting an error "Unable to reach app. Please try again" in popup. can you help me here pls

Comment: @Shaik Can you confirm if you have added the Bot id and password in the config file? Also could you please put a debugger and check what is the response you are getting?